# Python. Is digit should check for multiple number

Tags: python

I write small program on python just to learn how `split` and `isdigit` functions works

Program is:

```
s = input('type something:')
if s.isdigit():
    a = s.split()
    a = list(map(int, a))
    print('What you typed was number and it was converted to integer')
    print('Result is:', a)
else:
    a = s.split()
    print('What you typed was words it was not converted to integer')
    print('Result is:', a)
```

Question is what... When i type one single number  program works fine. `isdigit` checks for number. (Is really list contains of number).

When i type 4 (only one number - that's fine)

But when i type 3 6 4 2 6 3 multiple numbers `isdigit` can not check it

Why?

Comment: `3 6 4 2 6 3` is not a valid number to my knowledge... unless you know something I don't...

Comment: [RTM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit): _Return true if **all** characters in the string are digits_ Space is not a digit.

Comment: oh sorry i am so stupid

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is because `s` is  a variable of `string` type

If you want to check each symbol from string `s` whether it is digit you should try something like `[x.isdigit() for x in a]`.

Comment: This answer is wrong. String.isdigit() works exactly as he assumed, he just had a lot of non-digits in his string (spaces/blanks).
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Comment: The problem is not that the variable is of type string. And isdigit() already checks each character in the string of being a digit.

Comment: @frieder the thing is that even the string you wrote is "3 6 4 2 6 3". So what's wrong when I splitted it's values into a list and applied .isdigit() for each element, hmm? I don't get it

Comment: You said `It is because s is a variable of string type`
which is simply not correct because you even need a string to use String.isdigit(). And there is no reason to split up the string, check each single character and then aggregate the results because isdigit() already does that! Yes your code will work, it just adds an unneeded layer, but your answer in the context of his question is still wrong...

Answer (score 1):

As all the comments already say: A blank is not a digit and therefore the string "3 6 4 2 6 3" will return False.

```
>>> print("3 6 4 2 6 3".isdigit())
False
```

You can strip out all spaces by using the replace() function:

```
>>> print("3 6 4 2 6 3".replace(" ", "").isdigit())
True
```